# Functions on vectors as matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I know that we can think of matrices as functions that map vectors from one VS to another. However, if I was given an equation

$$T\vec{u}=\vec{w},$$

would I be able to say that $T$ is a matrix (or at least can be written as one)? That is, can all functions that map vectors to other vectors be represented as a matrix?

I am compelled to say yes. It may not always be an easy task to write $T$ as a matrix, but it seems like it is always possible to construct a matrix that does whatever $T$ is doing to our vectors since matrices are rather flexible with their elements. However, this is not a very rigorous reason.

Comment: The answer is no... however if you were to restrict yourself to **linear** functions mapping a *finite* vector space to another *finite* vector space, then yes.  There are plenty of bizarre functions out there who can not be represented as matrices.

Comment: For a simple counterexample, consider a function that maps the zero vector to a nonzero vector.